# 'utf-8' codec can't decode when using readshapefile on python basemap

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to read boundary from Canadian Map from [here](http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/access_acces/alternative_alternatif.action?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=gcma000b11a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20%20%206773&loc=http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/gcma000b11a_e.zip)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

m = Basemap(resolution='c', # c, l, i, h, f or None
            projection='merc',
            lat_0=56.1304, lon_0=106.3468,
            llcrnrlon=-141.0, llcrnrlat= 41.2, urcrnrlon=-52.3, urcrnrlat=69.8)

m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#46bcec')
m.fillcontinents(color='#f2f2f2',lake_color='#46bcec')
m.drawcoastlines()
```

until here everything works great, but when I try to add boundary,

```
m.readshapefile('mypaths/gcma000b11a_e/gcma000b11a_e', 'gcma000b11a_e')
```

I have this `utf-8` error:

the code is from this great [tutorial](http://www.datadependence.com/2016/06/creating-map-visualisations-in-python/)

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 11: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Is the shapefile a utf-8 endcoded text file?  If it's not a text file, you need to open the file using binary mode ('rb'), to avoid Python trying to decode to Unicode.  If it's a text file but not utf-8 encoded, you'll need to open it using the correct codec.

Comment: it's not a text file at all, the shapefile is .shp

Answer (score 4):

The shape file you linked in fact consists of 4 files (.dbf, .prj, .shp, .shx). The problem is the dbf file (gcma000b11a_e.dbf), which is not in utf-8. It contains french characters (like é). You have to convert this file to utf-8, then your code works.
An easy way to convert the .dbf file is to open it with libre office calc, and in the import dialog select "Unicode (UTF-8)". Save the file, and m.readshapefile will work.

Answer (score 3):

```py
m.readshapefile('mypaths/gcma000b11a_e/gcma000b11a_e', 
                'gcma000b11a_e', 
                default_encoding='iso-8859-15')
```

`default_encoding` variable change the encoding of `readshapefile` function.

Comment: `default_encoding="latin-1"` works for me as well

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer by @LowQualityDelivery